# How to do multiple methods in one FTP connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have code set up to do an FTP PUT with a file to an FTP server. First I have a method that checks if the file exists at the target location. Then if it does I have another method that deletes the file. Then I perform the FTP PUT to the target location.

Currently, I'm performing these 3 methods by setting up 3 separate FTP connections to the same server. However, I want to perform all 3 methods with one connection to the server. The reason is because I'm getting the following error after opening multiple connections to same FTP server: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Here are the 3 functions below. The first method, GetFileFromRemoteServer, is used to see if a file exists on the FTP server at target path. I use regex in some cases to get partial name match, or in other cases just do full name match.

I researched online that someone said it's possible to use the same ftp request object and just perform all methods you want and then close the connection. I tried to see if it works performing multiple methods on same request object and I got this error: This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.

Is there a way to perform all of them using one connection to the server?

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

```
public static List<FTPLineResult> GetFileFromRemoteServer(bool isSsl, string username, string password, string fileName, string dir, Regex regexPattern,
        bool getSingleFile = false)
{
        var output = new List<FTPLineResult>();
        var parser = new FTPLineParser();
        var isDone = false;

        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dir);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.ConnectionGroupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpConnectionGroup"];
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;

        if (isSsl)
        {
            request.EnableSsl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            request.EnableSsl = false;
        }

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    while (!isDone && !reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var result = parser.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

                        //if "*" is in file name, which means get partial match, replacing * with real file name content
                        if (regexPattern != null)
                        {
                            if (regexPattern.IsMatch(result.Name.ToLower().Trim()))
                            {
                                output.Add(result);
                            }

                        }

                        else if (result.Name.ToLower().Trim() == fileName.ToLower().Trim())
                        {
                            output.Add(result);

                            isDone = true;
                        }
                    }

                    return output;
                }
            }
        }
    }


private void DeleteExistingTargetFile()
{
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_params.FinalFolderTarget);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_params.Username, _params.Password);
        request.UsePassive = true;

        request.ConnectionGroupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpConnectionGroup"];
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        if (_params.IsSsl)
        {
            request.EnableSsl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            request.EnableSsl = false;
        }

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var status = response.StatusDescription;
        }
    }

private void DoFtpPut(Dictionary<StatusEnum, string> statusDict)
{
        int buffLength = 2048;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
        System.IO.FileInfo _FileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(_params.SourceFilename);

        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_params.TargetFilename));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.ConnectionGroupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpConnectionGroup"];
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_params.Username, _params.Password);
        request.UsePassive = true;

        if (_params.IsSsl)
        {
            request.EnableSsl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            request.EnableSsl = false;
        }

        using (var _Stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            //read file one chunk at a time in order to avoid out of memory exception
            using (var fileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead())
            {
                var contentLen = fileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

                while (contentLen != 0)
                {
                    _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                    contentLen = fileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                }
            }
        }

        statusDict[StatusEnum.ftpStatus] = Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the `FtpWebRequest` class. Try a proper FTP client - for example, http://netftp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think you're right. I'm actually trying this ftp client now: http://ftplib.codeplex.com/ Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do FTPPUT with only one connection using FtpWebRequest class. However, using FtpLib library allowed me to do exactly what I wanted, which was to check if file exists on ftp server target location, if it does then delete it, and then do ftp put, and finally move file to final location using a rename.

Here's where I downloaded ftplib library: ftplib.codeplex.com

Here's the code below:

```
using (FtpConnection ftp = new FtpConnection(host, _params.Username, _params.Password))
{

            try
            {
                ftp.Open(); /* Open the FTP connection */
                ftp.Login(); /* Login using previously provided credentials */

                ftp.PutFile(_params.SourceFilename, _params.TargetFilename); /* upload /incoming/file.txt as file.txt to current executing directory, overwrite if it exists */

                if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(_params.FinalDir)) /* check that a directory exists */
                {
                    ftp.CreateDirectory(_params.FinalDir);
                }

                if (ftp.FileExists(_params.FinalLocation))
                {
                    ftp.RemoveFile(_params.FinalLocation);
                }

                ftp.RenameFile(target, _params.FinalLocation);

                statusDict[StatusEnum.ftpStatus] = Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusDict[StatusEnum.ftpStatus] = Constants.ERROR_STATUS;
            }
        }
```